# Html rendering to pdf. Div tags not rendering properly

Tags: html, itext

I'm rendering html content to PDF which has 3 div tags.

- The 1st div content is rendered properly.
- The content in 2nd div is truncated at page end
- On next page, the 3rd div tag content is rendered
- At the end the remaining content of the 2nd div tag is rendered.

How can I avoid it? What might be the problem?

Tried break-inline : avoid but didn't work

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Answer (score -1):

I am now sure until getting the code but my experience is please check your setting. If it's A4 size then maybe it solves your problem.

Are there 2nd div contents that are too long?

Comment: Yes the content in second div is long and is added till end of first page. Then it starts the 3rd div content on 2nd page and finally adds the remaining content from 2nd div to the end